# What's time complexity of following modified bucket sort solution

Tags: time-complexity, bucket-sort

It's kind of bucket sort algorithm, trying to get K nearest locations from point (0,0). This is being done by calculating distances of these locations and bucketing them based on distance. If two locations are at equal distance then priority given to location with closet x and then y(if x values are same)

What is time complexity of following solution?
O(NlogN) or O(KNlogN) or anything else

```
// java

Input: int k, List<Location>
Output: List<Location>

public class Location {
    //constructor x and y
    int x;
    int y;
    //get 
    //set

    //hashcode and equals
}

public class Solution {
    public List<Location> returnKNearestLocation(int k, List<Location> locations) {
        Map<Float, Set<Location>> map = new TreeMap<>();
        for(Location loc: locations) {
            float dist = calculateDistance(new Location(0,0), loc);
            List<Location> temp = map.getOrDefault(dist, new HashSet());
            temp.add(loc);
            map.put(temp);
        }

        List<Location> result = new ArrayList<>();
        int size = k;
        while(size > 0) {
            for(Float key : map.keySet()) {
                Set<Location> loc = map.get(key);
                Collection.sort(loc, p1, p2 -> {
                        return p1.x.equals(p2.x)? p1.y.compare(p2.y) : p1.x.compare(p2.x);
                });

                for(Location currLoc : loc) {
                    result.add(currLoc);
                    if(result.size() == k) {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
                size = size - loc.size();
            }                
        }

        return result;
    }

    private float calculateDistance(Location p, Location q) {
       // calculate distance Math.sqrt((P.x - Q.x)^2 + (P.y - Q.y)^2)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say O(N*log(N)).

- Assuming `float dist = calculateDistance(new Location(0,0), loc)` is O(1).
- Implementations of `put()` and `getOrDefault()` in a `TreeMap` are O(log(N)). Other implementations offer O(1). I'd take a look at `HashMap`.
- Implementation of `add` in a `HashSet` is O(1) (amortized).
- Implementation of `add` in an `ArrayList` is O(1) (amortized)
- BucketSort has a worst-case of O(N^2), in the case that all items are placed in the same bucket.

I'd take a look at `HashMap` instead of `TreeMap`.

So, assuming I'm not wrong:

- The first loop (*foreach loc*) has a complexity of O(N*log(N)).
- The second loop (*while size > 0*) is O(N*log(N)).

  - Assuming all locations are placed in the same bucket, we'll sort all the items (O(N*log(N))).
  - Then we'll iterate through the first K elements, and add to result -- this takes O(K) < O(N).

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but why the complexity is not O(k*nlogn) because the (while size > 0)  loop will run `k` times and sorting of each list will take O(nlogn)
BTW the reason to treemap is, I want keys in sorted order as I want shortest location from Location(0,0)

Comment: if the loop runs `k` times, that means you had to go through `k` buckets of size 1. Sorting each of these 1-element buckets is O(1).

Comment: That scenario may be closer to what you'll observe, if most of the distances are different :-) but that's not the worst-case